# What are the options or best practice in how to specialize a class ? 

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, composition

I have an already created Person class with its respective attributes; eventually a person can turn into an Employee.

Using inheritance, Employee can be a subclass of Person. How can you transform ("specialize") this Person to an Employee without the need of transfering all of its attributes to the new Employee class ?

Is it better to have an independent (regarding inheritance) Employee class with an attribute of Person type  (as in often seen in DB) ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @downvoter, please help the OP to improve his question rather than silently downvoting and voting to close.

Comment: I don't quite get the question--do you mean that you eventually want to create an instance of `Employee` from a `Person`? You'd probably want `Employee.fromPerson(person)` or something similar then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible in Java. An object has a type, and can't acquire a new one. If it's a Person it will always be a Person, and will never be an employee. You can create a new object, of type Employee, from a Person, though :

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * copy constructor
     */
    protected Person(Person p) {
        this.name = p.name;
    }

    // ...
}

public class Employee extends Person {
    private String badge;

    public Employee(Person p, String badge) {
        super(p);
        this.badge = badge;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it the question is **inheritence (is-A) or composition(has-A)?**

Generally speaking these are often alternatives. And staying general, inheritence breaks encapsulation so it should not be overused/misused but Java has no support for composition in language at all.

To be specific - Employee is always Person, so the **having it as subclass is the right way**. It could be modeled as composition, Person instance beeing a property of the Employee class but saying "Employee has Person" (attribute) sounds pretty strange, so I'd avoid it unless I have some additional reasons for such solution.